# I can't animate my Shape keys

Tags: animation

Hi if i link a character to a new scene the shape keys and the object data tab aren't available anymore.

How can i animate my Shape keys like the eye blink in a linked blender scene?

Comment: Maybe, you mean Shape keys?

Answer (score 1):

You mast create a *driver* to the Shape key mix *value* for manipulating this value from a *Armature*.

1. In Shape keys click on Value of your Shape key and select *Add Driver* -> *manually create later*. Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> while hovering value slider by mouse. Driver will be violet:

[image]

2. Next in *Graph editor* - select *Drivers* mode:

[image]

3. On <kbd>N</kbd> -> *Drivers* panel setup driver like this:

[image]

Finally, check, can you manipulate shape key by moving bone in Pose mode?

And at last, in new scene press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>P</kbd> -> select armature object. It will creates a local copy of armature, and you will be able to manipulate the bone, that control your Shape key.